# Custom platform transaction manager in spring

Tags: spring, transactions

I'm trying to implement custom transactional cache in a spring boot application. I've created my own implementation of AbstractPlatformTransactionManager and some unit tests, which show transactions are working as expected. However the real application ignores my transaction manager - it`s methods are never called. What I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Transaction manager implementation:

```
@Component
public class CacheTransactionManager extends AbstractPlatformTransactionManager{
    @Override
    protected Object doGetTransaction() throws TransactionException {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Cache transaction configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class CacheTransactionConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "cacheTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager cacheTransactionManager() {
        return new CacheTransactionManager();
    }
```

}

Custom transactional annotation (I've tried also without this, but no difference):

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional(value = "cacheTransactionManager", rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public @interface CacheTransactional {

}
```

Cache service:

```
@Component
public class CacheService {
    @CacheTransactional
    public void add(Object o){
        ...
    }
}
```

Working JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
@Configuration
@EntityScan(...)
@IntegrationTest
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CacheTransactionManagerTest {
    @Autowired
    private CacheService cacheService;

    @Test
    @CacheTransactional
    public void transactionTest(){
        cacheService.add(new Object());
    }
}
```

Not working wicket application main class (ignores cacheTransactionManager):

```
@Configuration("MyApplication")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(...)
@EnableJpaRepositories(...)
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
@ComponentScan(...)
@ImportResource({...})
public class MyApplication extends AuthenticatedWebApplication {
...
}
```

My env: Java 8, Spring Boot 1.2.1, Spring 4.1.4, Spring data JPA 1.7.2, Hibernate 4.3.7, Apache Tomcat 8.0.15, Wicket 6.17.0

Comment: and how is the `@CacheTransactional` supposed to be handled exactly? Can you explain a bit more what you"re trying to do?

Comment: I want to achieve that before execution of a @CacheTransactional method is a transaction created (methods doGetTransaction and doBegin from transaction manager are called) and when the method finishes successfully, doCommit is called, otherwise (in case of an exception) doRollback is called. This works in junit tests, but doesn't work in application.

Answer (score 2):

I found out some new facts:

- when I remove AdviceMode.ASPECTJ from @EnableTransactionManagement on CacheTransactionConfiguration, transactions begin to work, but propagation of transaction is ignored - nested call from one @CacheTransactional method to another @CacheTransactional methods always creates new transaction. Same behavior in JUnit test and real application.
- when AdviceMode.ASPECTJ is on CacheTransactionConfiguration setted, but I remove @CacheTransactional annotation from junit test, transaction stops working also in juint (in test body is a @CacheTransaction method called, so there should be a transaction created).
- application log contains this entry:
  o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader isOverriddenByExistingDefinition:290 - Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=cacheTransactionManager,declaringClass=x.y.z.CacheTransactionConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'cacheTransactionManager' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.

So I can get this working, but without propagation...

Answer (score 0):

For propagation, you need to tell Spring's @Transactional what propagation mode to apply. You can define several tx annotations, each inherit from @Transactional, but with a different propagation mode.